# Howto close a TFS userstory when the last task is done

Tags: tfs

is there a way to automaticaly close a User-Story in TFS2010 when I checkin my code 
with the last open task ?

I do not want to add the User-Story to the checkin with the code.

Comment: Some process templates, such as [Scrum for Team System v3](http://scrumforteamsystem.codeplex.com), come with additional server-side processes to handle this. I assume since you reference the "user story" work item type that you are using the MSF Agile template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS can't do this automatically, however tools like http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/ can.

Answer (score 1):

As previously suggested, [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com) can indeed easily do this. Just be sure that you actually want to do this, because you might want a human eye to verify that the story is indeed done.

What I suggest is to use the aggregator not for *closing* the story, but for moving it to a **code complete** state (or "ready for UAT", or "deployable", or what-have-you), if your tasks do not, in fact, cover everything needed for **"DONE" done**.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not realy close the user story. It will be set to Test :-)